# What the heck IS this thang?

Tags: current, symbol

[image: loopy thingy]
Hey you kids! Don't putcher lips on it!

Seriously, I do not know what this symbol means.  Printed nearby says 14 mA at 10V.  Goes to ground from the inverting input of an LM833 op amp.

Anyone?

Comment: It looks like a light bulb.

Comment: @DerStrom8 A light bulb in a snow storm.

Comment: It's a poor man's current regulator with PTC effects affecting R value.

Comment: it is a leaf on a branch profiled against the full moon.  ..... it is a filament light bulb

Comment: @hyprfrcb given the 14mA/10v rating and the LM833 context, Tony's answer is exactly right. I often use filament light bulbs as 'constant current' loads (they're good at dissipation as well!). If you wanted to contribute to the forum you could have supported that intepretation with a comment, or even an answer!

Comment: lol at the down votes. Oh no my life is ruined.  Imagining Mel Brooks harrumphing.  Whew you really showed me.  This place is strict.

Answer (score 6):

Why are you hiding the context? (The question is **rhetorical**, my answer follows)

I would guess it is a small incandescent lamp used to stabilize the output amplitude of a [Wien bridge oscillator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_bridge_oscillator).

[image]

Edit: Here is the circuit OP drew the symbol from (from the op-amp [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm833-n.pdf)), which is exactly the same (but with values rather than the design equations).

The lamp has a positive temperature coefficient and a slow enough response time that it does not change significantly during a cycle of the oscillator. This is an important consideration as there is a trade-off between stabilization time of the oscillator and distortion. Probably something like a Chicago Miniature Lamp CM327 running at far less than rated voltage. The positive temperature coefficient means that the gain of the amplifier decreases as the output amplitude increases, stabilizing the output amplitude. It would otherwise tend to die off or would increase until the amplifier began to clip (introducing a lot of distortion) if you just adjusted a fixed resistor in place of Rb.

[image]

Sometimes the same function is achieved with LDR optocouplers or JFETs but it's hard to beat the simplicity (and RoHS compliance) of a tungsten-filament lamp.

Comment: yes Tungsten's high temp and PTC makes it a good constant current sink or soft limiter for unity gain.  I wanted to do this in my 1st design as a polyfuse before they were invented. It didn't fly to aerospace requirements.

Comment: Thanks Sphero and Tony.  The LM833 documentation shows it used in a sine wave oscillator application, but that osc version you show is also interesting.

Comment: @noogrub It's the same circuit, exactly, without credit given to  Max Karl Werner Wien. Edited in above.